# Symmetry and Algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, hilbert-space

I'm trying to get a more concrete idea how symmetry is understood in quantum theories, as broad as possible.

Consider a infinitesimal transformation of states in quantum physics of the form:

$$ |\phi'\rangle=(1+i\epsilon G)|\phi\rangle, \tag{1}$$

where $G$ is a (not necessarily Hermitian) operator, which may be associated with the transformation of any Hermitian operator $M$:

$$M'=M+i\epsilon G^\dagger M-i\epsilon MG, \tag{2}$$

so that the expectation value

$$\langle\phi'|M'|\phi'\rangle=\langle\phi|M|\phi\rangle \tag{3}$$

is invariant.

- If we consider the transformation $G$ to be symmetry, then any operator will create a symmetry transformation of the quantum physics. To what extend is this statement true?
- Generally symmetry is considered by group of symmetries. There is a group of finite transformation of $\epsilon G$ if and only if there is a closed algebra containing $G$. Then if we can construct a closed algebra of operators, can we associate it with a particular kind of symmetry?
- Finally, the whole above discussion is considered under quantum framework. How can we relate to the classical one?

Comment: Have you heard of [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_groups) and their algebras? That's the framework symmetries are usually discussed in, and since you mention them with nary a word, I thought I'd ask. Also, I don't understand your first bullet point - not every operator will be a symmetry, even though every operator transforms under the symetry.

Comment: As I see $G$ can be used to defined a transformation that reserve the scalar-the amplitude of the physics. Isn't that good enough to call it a symmetry>

Comment: Careful with the terminology! *Scalar* already means that the thing called scalar is *invariant under transformation*, i.e. transforms as an element of the trivial representation of the transformation group. "the amplitude of the physics" - if you mean leaving all expectation values of observables the same then yes, that's a symmetry. But if it has an "infinitesimal version", that is equivalent to saying the symmetry group is a Lie group. In classical physics, you must leave the Lagrangian/action/equation of motion invariant. (things doing the latter, not the former, are called anomalous)

Comment: (The above is a comment since I do not think that the question, as it stands, has good answers. It is not a bad question, but it seems to use a very peculiar understanding of symmetry/operators, and I believe most of the question itself goes away when translating it into "regular" physics terminology)

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): What are OP's definitions of symmetry inside the quantum framework in the first bullet point in order to have a non-trivial statement?

Comment: It seems like it's standard to find symmetry in classical meaning (invariance of Lagrangian...) then transfer it to the quantum version. However I think it's better to define symmetry inside the quantum framework.
You can check that, indeed, $M'$ is hermitian.